# Create a Netty ByteBuf

Tags: netty

If I just want to use ByteBuf not in a Netty application.I use `ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes)` to create a ByteBuf,must I call the `buf.release` in the end of the function?

```
 public void process(byte[] bytes) {

            ByteBuf frame = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);

//something
            frame.release();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnpooledHeapByteBuf.release` method implement like this:

```
@Override
public boolean release() {
    for (;;) {
        int refCnt = this.refCnt;
        if (refCnt == 0) {
            throw new IllegalReferenceCountException(0, -1);
        }

        if (refCntUpdater.compareAndSet(this, refCnt, refCnt - 1)) {
            if (refCnt == 1) {
                deallocate();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the `deallocate` method:

```
@Override
protected void deallocate() {
    array = null;
}
```

The heap memory can be recycle by garbage collector, so not call the `release` method maybe not make memory leak in theory in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

As rule of thumb you should always call `ByteBuf.release()` once your are done with using the `ByteBuf`. This will allow you to switch to direct buffers or pooled buffers later without any code changes.